# Java calls wrong python version

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to run a Python script from a Java program using Process and ProcessBuilder, however Java keeps using the wrong version of Python.  (The script needs 3.6.3 to run and Java runs Python 2.7)

However when I run the script from the terminal (outside of Java), it runs the correct Python (3.6.3).  How does one change what version of Python gets run when called by Java?

Comment: you'll need to provide more info.  How are you executing python from your script?  Can you show us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 3):

The short version is it changes with your `PATH` environment variable.

Under Windows, [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120) has the answer. Scroll down to the 'Command Search Sequence' section. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653492/4822566) explains it nicely.

For UNIX-like OS's, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/238993) is nicely detailed.

There are two very useful commands for determining which executable is going to be called: [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) for UNIX-likes and [`where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743878(v=vs.85).aspx) for newer Windows.

The most likely reason for the difference between Java and the terminal is a difference in your `PATH`. Perhaps your Java version is being run with a modified `PATH`? A launch script of some kind may be changing it.

Answer (score 2):

Add `/usr/bin/python3.4` to the start of your command to force the version of python you want. If you're not sure where python is installed, have a go at using `whereis python` and seeing what you get back.

```
private int executeScript(final List<String> command) {
    try {
        final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python3.4").command(command);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        System.out.println("executing: " + processBuilder.command().toString());

        final Process process = processBuilder.start();
        final InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        final InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();

        readStream(inputStream);
        readStream(errorStream);

        return process.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Then just pass in the `List` containing your python commands.