# Python runs version 3.5 instead of 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I've never had this kind of problem because I'm using PyCharm and it has perfect version control.

But now I'm using flask and running it in terminal using 'flask run' command and I've just noticed that it runs on python 3.5:

```
.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

When I type python --version it says '3.6.5' but I went to this ~/.local/lib directory and noticed that there's only 2 folders: python2.7 and python3.5

When I try to update python using

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

It says 'Requirement already satisfied.'

The reason I need python3.6 here because I can't run a flask app that contains an f-string.

Comment: Do you have a virtualenv set up?

Comment: yeah, and I created a new virtualenv via PyCharm. That's why Pycharm can run this code unlike the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify which runtime PyCharm should use, but in a shell (i.e. terminal), it's determined by your `PATH` environment variable.

For UNIX-like OS's (including MacOS and Linux), [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/238993) is nicely detailed.

Under Windows, [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120) has the answer. Scroll down to the 'Command Search Sequence' section. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653492/4822566) explains it nicely.

There are two very useful commands for determining which executable is going to be called: [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) for UNIX-likes and [`where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743878(v=vs.85).aspx) for newer versions of Windows.

Since `virtualenv` is being used, you should be able to run:

```
workon my_project_name
```

To use the existing virtual environment. Have a look at a [virtualenv tutorial](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) for more information.